# Ajax on Rails Controller and Update d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, d3.js

Here is the scenario: I have a Rails controller that stores a json of data using a start and end date as @data. In my view I have d3.js making that into a graph.

My goal: Im trying to create a form underneath the graph with a start and end date. Once I hit submit, I'd like to have it Reload the graph with the new data (using the start and end date inputs) it has to pull from a controller.

Right now my AJAX form looks like this but returns a 500:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => developers_dashboard_path(:host => developers, :action => :get_data),
    :html => {:action => {:controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'page'}, :id => 'test', :class => 'date-form'} do %>

    <%= text_field "start_date", "name", :value => @start_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :class => "input datepicker fleft" %>

    <%= text_field "end_date", "name", :value => @end_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :class => "input datepicker fleft" %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Apply' %>

<% end %>
```